# Guide how to create custom tile in BW/4HANA

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I tried to follow this tutorial on [How-To: Create custom tile types for OnPremise Fiori Launchpad](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/28/how-to-create-custom-tile-types-for-onpremise-fiori-launchpad/) to create a tile with line chart based on BW/4HANA system but I couldn’t even complete the step 1.1. because of missing dynamic files.

Is there a better and newer guide that you can recommend?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Don't have any read-to-go answers but the tutorial looks outdated; that's a Fiori 1 launchpad

Comment: Does this one help you https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3981331cbc074ec398ae735e7b449cce ?